# How to make safe continuous back to back fetches in browser JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I want to display a stream of images in a browser component.

So far I've tried something like

```
function fetchData() {
  fetch("data.png?")
     .then((response) => response.blob())
     .then((blob) => {
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            var width = canvas.width;
            var height = canvas.height
            
            myimage = new Image();
            myimage.onload = function() {
                    ctx.drawImage(myimage, 0, 0,width,height);
                    }
        const imageObjectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        myimage.src = imageObjectURL;           
       }

...
setInterval(fetchData, 50);
```

This sort of works. But if I make the `setInterval` period too short I start to get ERR_INSUFFICIENT_ RESOURCES error. I guess this is because fetch requests or responses pile up somewhere.

Ideally the drawing of a fetched image would trigger the next fetch. However I'm worried that sometimes no drawing will take place or a fetch might not complete in which case the process would stop.

Further I would like to have a few fetches in-flight to maximize performance and they should be completed in order, but without excessive buffering as the fetched data is interactive controlled from the browser so it is not like I would want to buffer a ten seconds worth of data.

So I'm looking for a general strategy implement above, I'm sure many people have worked on things like this before but I've not found examples.

Comment: Is the intended refresh rate really 20 frames per second?  That's closer to a *video* than a picture slideshow...

Comment: I'm aiming at max FPS, this is interactive, ie mouse action change the image content.

Comment: Perhaps related to your scenario (perhaps not), but mabe of interest to future readers ... don't forget the built-in lazy loading of IMG resources that is now available in HTML without any Javascript. This will delay loading until the image is onscreen.

https://caniuse.com/loading-lazy-attr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `setInterval` isn't appropriate because it doesn't count the fetch and image load time.
- To get max FPS you should call `fetchData` immediately after the drawing.
- I suggest to draw with `requestAnimationFrame` to avoid possible image render tearing.
- You should have some `stopped` flag to be able to stop the infinite cycle.
- Also you should avoid requesting the context for each renders, it's expensive.
- Also you could use more ES6+ features and avoid creating intermediate 1 line variables:

```js
// get ctx outside
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let stopped = false;

const delay = (delay = 0) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, delay));

async function fetchData() {
  
  const r = await fetch("data.png?");
  
  if(stopped) return;
     
  const [width, height] = canvas;
  const myimage = new Image();

  myimage.onload = () => {
    requestAnimationFrame(async () => {
      ctx.drawImage(myimage, 0, 0,width,height);
      
      await delay(50); // if you don't need a delay and need max FPS, remove that and async
      
      fetchData();
    }
  };
  myimage.src = URL.createObjectURL(await r.blob());           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have load event to use

You can even add to error, but I would give up after x amount of retries

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const width = canvas.width;
const height = canvas.height;

const fetchData = () => {
    fetch("data.png?")
      .then((response) => response.blob())
      .then((blob) => {
          myimage = new Image();
          myimage.onload = () => {
            ctx.drawImage(myimage, 0, 0, width, height);
            setTimeout(fetchData, 200); // 50 is silly
          }
          myimage.onerror = () => {
            setTimeout(fetchData, 200); 
          }
          const imageObjectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          myimage.src = imageObjectURL;
        }
      }
```